# Atom forge or Atomic forge?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What would be the correct form of this phrase?

> Atom forge

or

> Atomic forge

I know 'atomic' is an objective and 'atom' being a noun is correct when used with forge because you are forging something. But 'atomic' sounds right and I've seen that used before. Just want some clarification.

Comment: You haven't said what is being forged. Which is "correct" rather depends on that.

Comment: "Objective" (end result) or "adjective" (description)?

Comment: Both seem to be used for hypothetical techologies, but until atom(ic) forges become a widely-discussed practical technology we can't really say what term is more common. Use either, or take your lead from some particular scientist or technologist. This seems more of a question for another forum, whether you're interested in sci-fi and worldbuilding, or experimental physics.

Comment: Are you forging *atoms* themselves, or are you forging something using *atomic power*?

Comment: 'Correct' is probably not the correct term to use here, as neither 'atom forge' nor 'atomic forge' is disallowed on basic English grounds. On idiomaticity grounds, the situation is unclear because of low sample sizes and a lot of muddying by proper noun usages. [adjective vs noun-as-an-adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512836/adjective-vs-noun-as-an-adjective) explains the overall situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjective vs Noun as an adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512836/adjective-vs-noun-as-an-adjective) //  'Correct' is probably not the correct term to use here, as neither 'atom forge' nor 'atomic forge' is disallowed on basic English grounds. On idiomaticity grounds, the situation is unclear because of low sample sizes and a lot of muddying by proper noun usages. The linked thread explains the overall situation.